# Программа на C++: Ошибка C2084 функция "int ProverkaPravilnostiDanuh(int,int,int,int,int,int)" уже имеет текст реализации

Tags: visual-c++, инспекция-кода

Условие задачи:Дано координаты (как целые от 1 до 8) двух полей шахматной доски. Проверить, может ли конь за один ход перейти с одного поля на другое. Создать программу, в которой используется функция для исполнения проверки. Функция должна возвращать значения 1 (true) или 0 (false).
P.s. То есть ввести координаты где стоял конь, и координаты куда его переместить, если это по правилам то вернуть 1 если нет то ноль.

Жду любые советы и критику.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "math.h"

using namespace std;

int ProverkaPravilnostiDanuh(int i1, int j1, int i2, int j2, int r1, int r2) 
{}
int main()
{
    int Starti, Finishi, Startj, Finishj, r1, r2, c;
    cout << "Vvedite Kordinatu start i Finish " << endl;
    cin >> Starti >> Startj;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> Finishi >> Finishj;
    cout << endl;
    c = ProverkaPravilnostiDanuh(Starti, Startj, Finishi, Finishj, r1,r2);
    if (c == 0 || 1)
        cout << "Eto vozmojno";
    else
        cout << "Ne vernue kordnatu";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
    int ProverkaPravilnostiDanuh(int i1, int j1, int i2, int j2, int r1, int 
    r2){
    r1 = i2 - i1;
    r2 = j2 - j1;
    if (abs(r1) == 1 && abs(r2) == 2)
        return 1;
    else
        if (abs(r2) == 1 && abs(r1) == 2)
            return 1;
        else;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Стоит хотя бы код нормально отформатировать. Читать же невозможно, ну. :/

Comment: У вас вместо объявления и определения функции `ProverkaPravilnostiDanuh` присутствуют два определения.

Comment: Этот вопрос - дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418668 (ответ от Petr Abdulin) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765599

Comment: Три ответа, понимания ноль. Отформатировать код... мне бы с функциями работать научится. Объявления определения это конечно очень хорошо, но можно подробней, я ниче не понял.

Comment: @Anton Я бы с радостью понял, но я не понял. Уже задавали мой вопрос, но решения я там не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое

```
int ProverkaPravilnostiDanuh(int i1, int j1, int i2, int j2, int r1, int r2) 
{}
```

является не *объявлением*, а *определением*. Оставьте вместо него только объявление -

```
int ProverkaPravilnostiDanuh(int i1, int j1, int i2, int j2, int r1, int r2);
```

Иначе вы нарушаете *правило одного определения*...

И еще - это не бассейн, в котором нужно сначала залить воду, а потом учиться плавать :) Форматировать код - такую привычку нужно приобретать сразу.

Comment: Спасибо , помогло.